# how can I find CCSprites NSString value

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nsstring, ccsprite

Sorry guys, this one is beating it. How can I tell if a `CCSprite` has a given string value for it's `spriteWithSpriteFrameName`?

Comment: You want to get the name of current spriteframe name, or just want to know if the sprite was created with a spriteframe?

Comment: @Bivis: I am creating a lot of sprites. I just want to check if one of the created sprites has with a certain string value for it's image. For example, something like this `if (sprite.string = @"image.png")`

Answer (score 1):

I think the only choice you have is something like :

```
CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] textureForKey:@"image.png"];
if (tex && tex==sprite.texture) {
    // do your thing ... make certain you understand the
    // key semantics in cocos2d , re texture atlas
}
```

For myself, whenever getting a new 'cocos2d' version, i systematically add to CCNode a NSString *name property, which i use for various purposes, one of which is similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've tried a simple example to log a case that I know is satisfied. But it doesn't print to the console. `CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] textureForKey:@"redBall.png"];
`   `if (tex && tex==redBallSprite.texture) {`   `CCLOG(@"it's working"); }`

Comment: the code you provided above checks to see if a sprite is in a given texture. What I actually wanted was how to find if an individual `CCSprite` within a texture has a certain `NSString` value.